# Cmake: target_link_libraries propagation of include directories

Tags: cmake

I have a small static library that requires boost headers and that requires the "include" directory in the include directories.

```
...
add_library(alib STATIC ...)
target_include_directories(alib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_include_directories(alib PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
```

I have another installation on the system of *alib*, exactly where ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} point to, but this is an older version, required by other packages of my system. 
The point is that I want to build a custom version of *alib* as a target of my project. So this is very important that nothing from the system *alib* is being included or linked against.

Now I have another library *mylib* that depends on *alib*, so I do the following:

```
...
add_library(mylib STATIC ...)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC alib)
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
```

The `target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC alib)` call properly add includes from *alib* but it includes them AFTER the includes specified by the second line `target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIRS})`, even though they are specified afterwards.

Problem is that `${EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIRS}` points to the include path where the system *alib* is located.

It shouldn't matter if Cmake would correctly append include directories in the order they are provided, that is, the ones of `target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC alib)`then the ones of `target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIRS})`.

However cmake does not respect this order and appends the include directories from the call of target_link_libraries in the end of the command line, resulting in the system headers being picked up instead of my *alib* version headers.

I cannot change the name of directories of *alib* in any way.
My current solution is to hack a custom call to target_include_directories by referencing the *alib* target manually:

```
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:alib,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
```

Is there a better way of doing so? How can I force Cmake to include directories of *alib* **right-away** in the `target_link_directories` call, and not after ?

Answer (score 7):

No, your "hack" is more or less [the recommended way in the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements):

> For example, if the linked libraries for a target must be specified in the order `lib1` `lib2` `lib3`, but the include directories must be specified in the order `lib3` `lib1` `lib2`:
>
> ```
> target_link_libraries(myExe lib1 lib2 lib3)
> target_include_directories(myExe
>   PRIVATE $<TARGET_PROPERTY:lib3,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
> ```