# CMake include_directories isn't using one directory, but using all others around it

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, include, conda

I'm trying to use conda to manage several dependencies for a c++ library I'm building (I was previously using git submodules in my project's `external/` dir which worked fine, but for a number of reasons I wanted to migrate to conda).

The libraries I need to use are `tbb`, `zstd`, and `cspice`.  I've verified they are all installed correctly by conda, and are in my environment (named `vira_env`).  The headers are very clearly in `~/mamba_envs/vira_env/include/`.

However when I add `include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)` to my root CMakeLists.txt and run cmake using `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CONDA_PREFIX}`, it fails to find any of the headers.

Running `make VERBOSE=1` reveals that g++ has no `-I` argument to include the `~/mamba_envs/vira_env/include/` directory.  Which makes sense, as it is failing to find the headers that are there.

However, if I use `include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})` and rerun `make VERBOSE=1`, or it clearly shows that g++ has a `-I /home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/`.

Similarly, if I use `include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/oneapi)` it shows g++ has a `-I /home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/include/oneapi`.  (oneapi is the directory where the `tbb` headers are placed).

So `include_directories()` will happily use either the conda environment root, or even one of the directories inside the conda environment's include/ directory...  but it will just completely ignore the include/ directory itself.

### EDIT

As discovered in one of my comments below, printing `CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` shows `/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/include`.  Which explains why my `include_directories()` is not having any effect on the g++ call by make, since it believes that the compiler should be looking in that directory already.

`make VERBOSE=1`is showing that the compiler being used is: `/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++`.  However using `which g++` is showing `~/mamba_envs/vira_env/bin/g++`.  Further, which `ld` returns: `~/mamba_envs/vira_env/bin/ld`.

If I use `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`, it does not show `/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/include`.  Neither does `~/mamba_envs/vira_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`.

Comment: In modern CMake you may just want to use target_link_libraries() which handles the include folder dependency in addition to linking if the target is properly setup. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175683/cmake-target-link-libraries-propagation-of-include-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175683/cmake-target-link-libraries-propagation-of-include-directories)

Comment: So I just tried this.  I used `find_package(TBB REQUIRED)` which finds the `TBB_DIR` to be: `/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/lib/cmake/TBB`.  I then changed my `target_link_libraries(vira PRIVATE PUBLIC TBB:tbb .....)` however it still failed to find the headers.  Looking at the `TBBConfig.cmake` and `TBBTargets.cmake` found in that TBB_DIR, it looks as though its setup correctly.  But again, no additional `-I` flags are set in the g++ command when I run make VERBOSE=1

Comment: I guess that CMake detects `/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/include` to be one of the **implicit** include directory used by the compiler. You can check that by printing value of [CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) variable. CMake takes information about implicit include directories not directly from the compiler, but from the different platform files shipped with CMake. I remember recent questions about CMake incorrectly work in case of virtual env.

Comment: Using CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for this is really weird. Remembe that cmake expects to build your program, and then install it, and does sometimes edit paths from one to the other - e.g. when your program isn't installed yet it'll look for include files in your project dir, but once it's installed it'll look for include files in /usr/include. So I bet using the install path is confusing cmake. What if you call the variable something different?

Comment: Yeah it looks like you're right.  printing `CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` shows `/home/cgnam/mamba_envs/vira_env/include`.  I'm at a bit of a loss

Comment: @user253751 I don't have root access on this machine and so cannot install anything in /usr/include.  My goal with using conda was to be able to install things into the conda environment to get around that problem.